# Dois Aplicativos o Mesmo Banco

Tags: firebase

Eu tenho dois Aplicativos são de Delivery os dois se conectam um com outro um do restaurante e outro do Cliente onde ele pode fazer os pedidos e consultar o cardápio,etc.
Minha duvida é a seguinte posso usar o mesmo projeto banco de dados Firebase ou voou ter que criar dois projetos separados e conectar eles?

Answer (score 0):

Depende,

Você terá que codificar de tal forma que não possa haver duas aplicações editando o mesmo registro.

O correto seria haver apenas um back-end onde o mesmo irá validar se as requisições recebidas são oriundas da aplicação do cliente ou da aplicação do estabelecimento.

Comment: Sim sim eu entendi agora eles não podem fazer o login com mesmo email nas aplicações ja a parte de escrever não terá problema por que o próprio front-end não vai permitir isso

Comment: O mais correto seria haver apenas um back-end para ambas aplicações e dois front-end.

Comment: exatamente o que farei obg